# Dielectric between two like-charged plates

Tags: dielectric

I have read that a dielectric can be inserted between two capacitor plates, thereby increasing capacitance of the capacitor. But what happens if we try to insert a dielectric between two like-charged plates(both positive or both negative)? Can i insert the dielectric at all,and if i do so,what can be the consequences?

Comment: Wouldn't the electric field between plates be $0$ then?

Comment: Inserting the dielectric would decrease the repulsive force between the plates.

Comment: @Druv Maroo how does the dielectric reduce the repulsive force?

Comment: @BobD In the calculation of the total force between the plates after the insertion of the dielectric, instead of $\epsilon_0$, we will write $\epsilon_r × \epsilon_0$, where $\epsilon_r$ is the dielectric constant which is always $\geq 1$. So if we calculate the final repulsive force between two large charged plates having surface charge density $\sigma$ and area $A$, then it comes out to be, $F=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0}$. But in the dielectric case, the force would be, $F=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0 × \epsilon_r}$, which is clearly less than the force in the case without dielectric.